# Jenkins Slave Failure

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

I am running jenkins in kubernetes and tried to create a custom container to run the slaves with.   I configured jenkins to pull my docker container and that seems to be working as expected (pulling it and starting it in K8s).

Unfortuanately I am getting an Access Denied Exception when running my pipeline.  Not sure why I could be getting this error:

> Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to
>   JNLP4-connect connection from 10.40.0.25/10.40.0.25:54108         at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
>         at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
>         at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)       at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1036)       at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)       at
>   hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1208)        at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:810)       at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1180)      at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
>         at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
>         at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
>         at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>         at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)        at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /root/workspace  at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:308)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:746)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3098)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.access$900(FilePath.java:209)     at
>   hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1216)     at
>   hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1212)     at
>   hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2913)  at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)     at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Finished: FAILURE

DockerFile - the one that I used to create my slave container

```
FROM gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/jenkins-k8s-slave
USER root
### INSTALL PRE REQUISITES
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y golang docker
```

Jenkinsfile - super simple pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Download Code') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checking Out SCM..'
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Build container') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t golangwebserver:minimal --build-arg KEY=$GITHUB_OATH_KEY -f DockerFiles/Dockerfile .'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The image already sets the `USER` as `root`, so the line in your Dockerfile might be redundant. Are you defining any environment variables for the Jenkins agent pod?